# if I have a number of master detail entities, alter a detail record, can I update the whole lot in one transaction in EF?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I have a master entity and a series of detail entities which each map to an EF Entity.

Car -< Door

Car-< Window

My forms update all aspects of this car class ie

Car,

Car.Door

Car.Window

Once all the inserts and edits have happened, It would be neat to just do a Car.Save which would then save all the sub class data as well if those close have been modified, as opposed to saving each class individually.

This is probably standard EF fare, but some guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your update in one transaction using `TransactionScope`

This looks like:

```
using(var transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
    //do something with entities in dbcontext and save changes
    transaction.Complete();
}
```